# runas /netonly yields DLL import errors with python

Tags: python, windows, dll, anaconda, runas

After running `runas /netonly /user:domain\username "ipython"` on windows cmd, IPython 3.8.8 (installed via Anaconda) successfully launches but as soon as I start importing packages, I get DLL load failed errors. For example if I run `import nltk` or `import matplotlib.pyplot` I get the following error messages respectively:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1d2184025e54> in <module>
----> 1 import nltk

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py in <module>
    147 from nltk.tag import *
    148 from nltk.tokenize import *
--> 149 from nltk.translate import *
    150 from nltk.sem import *
    151 from nltk.stem import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\translate\__init__.py in <module>
     21 from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu as bleu
     22 from nltk.translate.ribes_score import sentence_ribes as ribes
---> 23 from nltk.translate.meteor_score import meteor_score as meteor
     24 from nltk.translate.metrics import alignment_error_rate
     25 from nltk.translate.stack_decoder import StackDecoder

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\translate\meteor_score.py in <module>
      8
      9
---> 10 from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
     11 from nltk.corpus import wordnet
     12 from itertools import chain, product

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\__init__.py in <module>
     27 from nltk.stem.isri import ISRIStemmer
     28 from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
---> 29 from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
     30 from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
     31 from nltk.stem.rslp import RSLPStemmer

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\snowball.py in <module>
     27 import re
     28
---> 29 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
     30 from nltk.stem import porter
     31 from nltk.stem.util import suffix_replace, prefix_replace

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\__init__.py in <module>
     64 from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
     65 from nltk.corpus.util import LazyCorpusLoader
---> 66 from nltk.corpus.reader import *
     67
     68 abc = LazyCorpusLoader(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\__init__.py in <module>
    103 from nltk.corpus.reader.categorized_sents import *
    104 from nltk.corpus.reader.comparative_sents import *
--> 105 from nltk.corpus.reader.panlex_lite import *
    106 from nltk.corpus.reader.panlex_swadesh import *
    107

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\panlex_lite.py in <module>
     13
     14 import os
---> 15 import sqlite3
     16
     17 from nltk.corpus.reader.api import CorpusReader

~\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py in <module>
     21 # 3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.
     22
---> 23 from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py in <module>
     25 import collections.abc
     26
---> 27 from _sqlite3 import *
     28
     29 paramstyle = "qmark"

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found.
```

AND

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-864e826dab68> in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>
    172
    173
--> 174 _check_versions()
    175
    176

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in _check_versions()
    157     # Quickfix to ensure Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable
    158     # DLLs are loaded before importing kiwisolver
--> 159     from . import ft2font
    160
    161     for modname, minver in [

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ft2font: The specified module could not be found.
```

However, imports such as `import numpy` or `import pandas` run fine.

Furthermore, when launching "ipython" **without** `runas` all imports run perfectly.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

EDIT:

1. I can confirm that it is not an administrative thing.
2. I installed python independently from Anaconda - and now when I run `runas /netonly /user:domain\username "C:\somenewpath\python"`, importing `nltk` and `matplotlib` are successful. However, this is not necessarily ideal for two reasons: 1) because I have to manually install a host of packages, and 2) now I have 2 separate python IDLEs sitting in my environment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See edit #2 - I have a workaround but its not ideal... and it seems to indicate that the problem is with the way Anaconda installs the different packages.